# mongodb avoid inconsistencies

Tags: mongodb, transactions

Given the following scenario:

Collection Products with a document Product(id, owner), and a document p1(1, "bob")

- Request1:  read p1
- Request2:  read p1
- Request2:  update p1 name="karen" (if owner was "bob" during previous read)
- Request1:  update p1 name="laura" (if owner was "bob" during previous read)

Both updates will succeed, correct? And the result will be "laura" as far as I understand MongoDB. However, can I simply resolve this by adding a where clause name="bob" because the changes are in one document, or do I need more advanced features such as transactions? Or is this only for multi document updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both updates will succeed, correct?

Yes.

Assuming that the update method is like this: `db.collection.updateOne( { id: 1 }, { owner: name } )`, where the `id` is a unique product id field and the "name" value is either "laura" or "karen" depending upon the request. Both updates will succeed.

But, the *final* result could be "laura" or "karen". You don't know which update will reach the database first. So, there is no guarantee that what will be the value of `owner` in the document, after the update.

Note that read and update are two separate operations (as in CRUD). Having read a document doesn't mean a request owns the document in any way. The documentation says "In MongoDB, an operation on a single document is atomic"; this applies to update operations too.

> And the result will be "laura" as far as I understand MongoDB.

May be.

Unless somehow you are controlling the order in which the updates are happening in the database, there is no guarantee what  the final result will be.

> However, can I simply resolve this by adding a where clause name="bob"
>   because the changes are in one document, or do I need more advanced
>   features such as transactions? Or is this only for multi document
>   updates?

Adding a where clause like this `db.collection.updateOne( { id: 1, owner: "bob"}, { owner: name } )` will make sure that only one update operation will take place. Again, which update happens is not guaranteed.

> Transactions?

Transactions can be used with replica-sets (MongoDB version 4.0+) and shard clusters (MongoDB version 4.2+) only; not available with standalone MongoDB installations.

Does your application with the above scenario require a transaction? No. The update is a single operation and MongoDB guarantees it as an atomic operation. Generally, transactions are useful when there are multiple CRUD operations to be performed as a single unit (e.g., an invoice generation may create an invoice document and update the inventory and accounts collections - all operations happen as a unit or not happen at all).